# how to update a mysql table efficiently with a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I'm doing ETL with Airflow PythonOperator to update a SCD1 dimension table (`dim_user`).

The structure of the mysql dimension table:

```
| user_key | open_id             | gender | nickname | mobile      | load_time           | updated_at          |
|----------|---------------------|--------|----------|-------------|---------------------|---------------------|
| 117      | ohwv90JTgZSn******* | 2      | ABC      | ************| 2019-05-24 10:12:44 | 2019-05-23 19:00:43 |
```

In the python script, I have a same structure (except the user_key and load_time column) pandas dataframe `df_users_updated`.

Now I want to update the mysql table on the condition of `open_id` field matched:

```py
# database connection
conn = create_engine(db_conn_str)

# update the rows with a for loop
for index, row in df_users_updated.iterrows():
    info = dict(row)
    conn.execute('update dim_user set gender=%s, nickname=%s, mobile=%s, updated_at=%s where open_id=%s',
    (info['gender'], info['nickname'], info['mobile'], info['updated_at'], info['open_id']))
conn.dispose()
```

The problem is I only have 1000 rows in the df_users_updated, it toke over 10 minutes to execute these update queries.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on my experience, there are some tricks could improve the performance.

1. use `mysqlclient` lib, `cursor.executemany(sql, params)` method
2. use `tuple` type of params
3. use index on the where fields.